# Swift - UIImagePickerController - how to use it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying hard to understand how this works, but it's pretty hard for me. =)
I have 1 view, there is one button and one small ImageView area for preview.
The button triggers imagepickercontroller, and the UIView will display picked image.
There is no error but the image doesn't show in the UIImageView area.

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
@IBOutlet var imagePreview : UIImageView

@IBAction func AddImageButton(sender : AnyObject) {
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.presentModalViewController(imagePicker, animated: true)
    
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
    var tempImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)
    imagePreview.image  = tempImage
    
    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
    
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!) {

    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: are you creating your imagePreView programatically? If it is present in XIB or storyboard, check whether if you have connected your IBOutlet or not.

Comment: Please share the initialization code for `imagePreview`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're grabbing a `UIImage` named `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` and there exists no such image. You're meant to grab the `UIImage` with the key `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` from the `editingInfo` dictionary:

```
let tempImage = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

Comment: Thanks. But now I got fatal error : Can't unwrap Optional.None

Comment: On the line you want me to add. Do you know what does this mean?

Comment: That means either that `editingInfo` is `nil` (which I don't think), or that `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` does not exist in the dictionary. You're implementing an old method, you're meant to implement `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` and not `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:`.

Answer (score 34):

### Details

- Xcode 11.4.1 (11E503a), Swift 5.2

### More

[How to build own photo picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43142198/4488252)

### Solution

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Photos

protocol ImagePickerDelegate: class {
    func imagePicker(_ imagePicker: ImagePicker, grantedAccess: Bool,
                     to sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType)
    func imagePicker(_ imagePicker: ImagePicker, didSelect image: UIImage)
    func cancelButtonDidClick(on imageView: ImagePicker)
}

class ImagePicker: NSObject {

    private weak var controller: UIImagePickerController?
    weak var delegate: ImagePickerDelegate? = nil

    func dismiss() { controller?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }
    func present(parent viewController: UIViewController, sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.sourceType = sourceType
        self.controller = controller
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            viewController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Get access to camera or photo library

extension ImagePicker {

    private func showAlert(targetName: String, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Access to the \(targetName)",
                                            message: "Please provide access to your \(targetName)",
                                            preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default, handler: { action in
                guard   let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),
                        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) else { completion?(false); return }
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, options: [:]) { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.showAlert(targetName: targetName, completion: completion)
                }
            }))
            alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in completion?(false) }))
            UIApplication.shared.windows.filter { $0.isKeyWindow }.first?
                .rootViewController?.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func cameraAsscessRequest() {
        if delegate == nil { return }
        let source = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
        if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) ==  .authorized {
            delegate?.imagePicker(self, grantedAccess: true, to: source)
        } else {
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { [weak self] granted in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                if granted {
                    self.delegate?.imagePicker(self, grantedAccess: granted, to: source)
                } else {
                    self.showAlert(targetName: "camera") { self.delegate?.imagePicker(self, grantedAccess: $0, to: source) }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func photoGalleryAsscessRequest() {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let source = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
            if result == .authorized {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    self.delegate?.imagePicker(self, grantedAccess: result == .authorized, to: source)
                }
            } else {
                self.showAlert(targetName: "photo gallery") { self.delegate?.imagePicker(self, grantedAccess: $0, to: source) }
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: UINavigationControllerDelegate

extension ImagePicker: UINavigationControllerDelegate { }

// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

extension ImagePicker: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                               didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            delegate?.imagePicker(self, didSelect: image)
            return
        }

        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            delegate?.imagePicker(self, didSelect: image)
        } else {
            print("Other source")
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        delegate?.cancelButtonDidClick(on: self)
    }
}
```

### Full Usage

> Info.plist

```
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>bla-bla-bla</string>
 <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>bla-bla-bla</string>
```

> ViewController **(do not forget to paste solution code)**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    private lazy var imagePicker: ImagePicker = {
        let imagePicker = ImagePicker()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        return imagePicker
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "camera", style: .plain, target: self,
                                                           action: #selector(cameraButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "photo", style: .plain, target: self,
                                                           action: #selector(photoButtonTapped))

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 80, width: 200, height: 200))
        imageView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.imageView = imageView
    }

    @objc func photoButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) { imagePicker.photoGalleryAsscessRequest() }
    @objc func cameraButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) { imagePicker.cameraAsscessRequest() }
}

// MARK: ImagePickerDelegate

extension ViewController: ImagePickerDelegate {

    func imagePicker(_ imagePicker: ImagePicker, didSelect image: UIImage) {
        imageView.image = image
        imagePicker.dismiss()
    }

    func cancelButtonDidClick(on imageView: ImagePicker) { imagePicker.dismiss() }
    func imagePicker(_ imagePicker: ImagePicker, grantedAccess: Bool,
                     to sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
        guard grantedAccess else { return }
        imagePicker.present(parent: self, sourceType: sourceType)
    }
}
```

### Images

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: + *import "UIKit"*

Answer (score 24):

```
import MobileCoreServices

class SecondViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

   @IBOutlet var img:UIImageView!=nil

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
   {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

   }

   @IBAction func buttonTapped(AnyObject)
   {
     if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){
            println("Button capture")
            var imag = UIImagePickerController()
            imag.delegate = self
            imag.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
            //imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage];
            imag.allowsEditing = false
            self.presentViewController(imag, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
   }

   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
        let selectedImage : UIImage = image
       //var tempImage:UIImage = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
        img.image=selectedImage
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)    
   }
 }
```

Comment: I guess delegate method is changed to                                                         func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

Comment: func imagePickerController didFinishPickingImage editingInfo is deprecated like from iOS 3
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/

Answer (score 12):

Since **swift 4.2** and **xcode 10** the `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])` change a bit.

at the function header the infoKey-Section changes from

`didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]` to

`didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]`

To get the originalImage you now have to call:

`let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage` or

`let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage`

find other infoKeys [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/infokey) (editedImage, imageURL and more...)

Comment: Doesn't work for me: "Type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'originalImage'"

Answer (score 8):

**In Swift 5.2, iOS 14.2**

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false //If you want edit option set "true"
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
    imgRoom.image  = tempImage
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:NSDictionary!) {
    let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    imagePreview.image  = tempImage
```

or you can also use `?` in place of `!`.