# Swift 2: UIImagePickerController returning nil or object that is not UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I just got an isolated crash report for `imagePickerController:picker: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` with an `EXC_BREAKPOINT` message (which I understand typically occurs when force-unwrapping a nil value). The code that crashed is:

```
public func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    picker.delegate = nil

    // ...do something with pickedImage...
}
```

I assume I need to check that a UIImage has been returned like this:

```
public func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    picker.delegate = nil

    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        // ...do something with pickedImage...
    }
    else {
        // Show unsupported media type error dialog
    }
}
```

I have the picker media types set to image:

```
picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
```

So I am surprised `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is returning something other than a UIImage. Any ideas why or what might be returning?

Comment: You should properly tag your question as Swift2

Comment: Added swift2, but it is still swift so left the swift tag.

Comment: Beyond the `picker.delegate = nil`, your code is the same as mine (converted to Swift 3). Cn you duplicate the issue? If so, what if you commented out setting your controller delegate to nil?

Comment: Just to check, did you want info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] or info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] . The edited one

Comment: Editing is disabled in the picker, so the original image, thanks.

Comment: @dfd I can't duplicate the issue because all I have is a crash log, and I don't know what could have been returned other than a `UIImage`. The difference in the code is I am not force-unwrapping the supplied object to a UIImage. I think it is proper practice to set any delegate to nil when it is no longer in use and don't think that is what caused the crash.

Comment: try my full sample of using imagePicker http://stackoverflow.com/a/43426712/4488252

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I'm seeing similar crash in my app. Did you figure out why you got EXC_BREAKPOINT ?

Comment: I was never able to definitively solve the issue because I could not reproduce it. All I had was the crash log.