# how I show image name on button ? When we Uploading it?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am uploading an image via click on button and I want to show image name on same button (Which I am using to upload image) how can I do ?

```
    @IBAction func btnChooseImageAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum   {
        print("Button capture")

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
     }
```

Comment: check this link to make use of `UIImagePickerController` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625687/swift-uiimagepickercontroller-how-to-use-it

Comment: Follow this link to get image name from library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627901/how-to-get-file-name-in-uiimagepickercontroller-with-asset-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the complete and Proper code to get any image name on button. When we upload it.

```
    @IBAction func btnChooseImageAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Choose From", message: "Choose an image from.", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        print("Clicked on Camera")

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)
        {
            self.picker.sourceType = .camera

            //check device camera front or rear availabilty
            if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.front)
            {
                self.picker.cameraDevice = .front
                //cehck for flash
                if UIImagePickerController.isFlashAvailable(for: .front)
                {
                    self.picker.cameraFlashMode = .on
                }
            }
            else
            {
                self.picker.cameraDevice = .rear

                if UIImagePickerController.isFlashAvailable(for: .front)
                {
                    self.picker.cameraFlashMode = .on
                }
            }




            //check what you want to capture photo or video
            self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
            self.picker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
            })
        }
    }

    let gallery = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

        print("Clicked on Gallery")

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary)
        {
            self.picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.picker.allowsEditing = true

            self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

            })
        }
    }

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        print("Clicked on Cancel")
    }

    actionSheet.addAction(gallery)
    actionSheet.addAction(camera)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancel)

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true) { () -> Void in

    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        imageview.image = image
        let sonu = getFileName(info: info)
        print(sonu)
        if sonu == "JPG"
        {
            imageDataForApi = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        }
        else if sonu == "PNG"
        {
            imageDataForApi = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0)
        }
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in

    }

}

func getFileName(info: [String : Any]) -> String {

    if let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetPath], options: nil)
        let asset = result.firstObject
        let fileName = asset?.value(forKey: "filename")
        let fileUrl = URL(string: fileName as! String)
        if let name = fileUrl?.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent {
            print(name)


     //let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
            if (assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix("JPG")) {
                sonu = "JPG"
                print("JPG")
            }
            else if (assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix("PNG")) {
                sonu = "PNG"
                print("PNG")
            }
            else if (assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix("GIF")) {
                sonu = "GIF"
                print("GIF")
            }
            else {
                sonu = "Unknown"
                print("Unknown")
            }

            return name
        }
    }
    return ""

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the UIImagePickerController to select the image and upload on the server. Please follow the below steps to get the file name

Step 1.
`import AssetsLibrary
 import Photos`

Step 2. *Make sure in Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.*

Step 3. Image Picker Controller delegate method to get the info of the selected image

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL
    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url], options: nil)
    let fileName = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: assets.firstObject!).first!.originalFilename
    print("fileName = \(fileName)")

 dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

NOTE: there can be some warning which you can resolve by looking into the documentation or google search.
If this answer helps you please vote for it.