# How to get image name using UIImagePicker? I got image name but its working only in simulators not in actual devices

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to pick the image name from photo library . I am using UIImagePicker and I got image name , but its working only in simulators not in actual devices.

Comment: should be a lot of answers here in SO for this question like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625687/swift-uiimagepickercontroller-how-to-use-it

Comment: I tried many answers posted in stack overflow . But that's only working in simulators.

Comment: Did you allow the use of Photos in your app? you need to add in info.plist file this key "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" with a message, let me know if solves your issue

Comment: Thats already added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:
In your UIImagePickerControllerDelegate:

```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset {
        let assetResources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset)

        print(assetResources.first!.originalFilename)
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It may helps you. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this code. But its only working in simulator .. In actual device getting null value. I don't know why

Comment: Modified the answer please try this

Comment: I using iOS 12, but i don't see "UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset" in dic "info".

Comment: @AMP please Click the Up arrow of my answer so that another user get the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfectly working code for this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.dismissMe();
    if let picImgURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL {
        let imageName = picImgURL.lastPathComponent
    }
}
```