# 'UIImage?' is not convertible to 'UIImage' issue in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to implement an image picker. In the delegate method I am getting the following error.

[image]

or

[image]

Here is the code, I wrote

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    var image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage
    if image == nil {
        image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
    }

    simpleImagePicker!.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

I tried this using Swift 5 and it is working without error. But the issue is with Swift 4.

How to resolve this? Is there any solution for it?

Comment: try this var image = info[.editedImage] as! UIImage

Comment: Which version of Swift 4? 4.0? 4.1? 4.2? The signature for the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is different in different versions of Swift.

Comment: @YogeshPatel No, don't do that. It will crash if there is no edited image.

Comment: I am not getting any error, I just copied and paste your code! Can you pls change the variable name and try?

Comment: Yes we can do like guard and let statement too

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41128251/8201581

Comment: I am using swift 4.0 (not 4.1 or 4.2)

Comment: check this url it working for swift 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` signature is different for different Swift versions. You are using the method of Swift 4.2 and later which is far different from Swift 4.0.

> Swift 4.0:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

    } else if let originalimage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

    }
}
```

> Swift 4.2 & Swift 5:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {

    } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {

    } else {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
}
```

So, check the proper swift version and follow the proper methods!

Comment: @sohail your first ans is not giving an error for swift 4.0. Let me check once and I will updated here.

Comment: @MKiOS Sure, let me know if you still face any error in any of the `Swift` version.

Comment: @MKiOS I must suggest that you pls upgrade your code to latest `Swift` version, i.e., `Swift 5.0` and use Xcode 10.2.1

Answer (score 1):

> I tried this using Swift 5 and it is working without error. But the issue is with Swift 4.

First of all, if you're using Xcode 10.x I strongly suggest you to perform the Swift 5 update. Forget Swift 4 and stay updated.

Second, this is the right `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` implementation on Swift 5:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        // do stuff with your original image...

    } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        // do something with your edited image...
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Anyway, if you want to stick to `Swift 4`, this is the ImagePicker delegate function to use:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage {
            // do stuff with your image
        } else if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage {
            // do stuff with your image
        }
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the error. The OP already knows this works under Swift 5. The question is asking why that specific error is happening under Swift 4 (presumably Swift 4.0).

Comment: yes, but in programming you need to get updated, this is how this world goes so Swift 4 is gone, I just wanted to suggest him to update to Swift 5, which is the right thing to do :)

Comment: While I agree the best solution is to stay current, that comment doesn't address the question being asked. The OP specifically asked why they are getting that error in Swift 4. Telling them to use Swift 5 doesn't answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that there's no UIImagePickerController.InfoKey in Swift 4.
The compiler could not define this type, which causes the error
If you use correct signature for swift 4 with [String: Any] dictionary, the error will disappear